# Find the maximum of an expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> If $a,b,c$ and $d$ are positive integers such that 
>   $$a+b+c+d = 63$$
>   Find the maximum value of $$ab +bc +cd$$

My turn :
Using AM-GM
$$4ab \leq (a+b)^2$$
Then
$$4(ab + bc + cd) \leq (a+b)^2 + (b+c)^2 + (c+d)^2$$
But i did not go on any more

Comment: I believe that the solution of this question is presented on YouTube.https://youtu.be/0Ai9ygHu3L4

Comment: i got $$991$$ for the maximum and $$a=1,b=30,c=31,d=1$$

Answer (score 2):

This is just $(a+c)(b+d)-ad$. Note that the first term, is maximised when $a+c$ and $b+d$ are very close, say 31 and 32, and the last term is minimised when $ad$ is small. But it stil has to be at least 1. Thus $$(a+c)(b+d)-ad\le (a+c)(63-(a+c))-1\le 31\times32-1=991$$ with equality if we take $(1,30,31,1)$ or $(1,31,30,1)$

Comment: Nice solution!!